# PostAsJsonAsync Failed to fetch

Tags: razor, blazor, .net-6.0

I am new to Blazor WASM and cannot get PostAsjsonAsync working.

I have a customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Site> Sites { get; set; }
}
```

and a webapi endpoint which looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] Customer customer)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid request");
            }
            else
            {
                _dbContext.Customers.Add(customer);

                var result = await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                if (result <= 0)
                {
                    return StatusCode(500, "Error saving customer!");
                }
                else
                {
                    return Ok(result);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
            return StatusCode(500, ex);
        }
    }
```

In the App I'm using a simple PostAsJsonAsnc Method to call the endpoint:

```
 var response = await _http.PostAsJsonAsync<Customer>("http://localhost:5132/customers", customer);
```

here is the serialized version of the test customer:

```
{"CustomerID":0,"Name":"o","Description":"o","Sites":[]}
```

If I use postman the endpoint get called and everything is working.
Using the app I get "Failed to fetch".

BTW: GET Requests are working.

I have also tried:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:5132/customers")
            {
                Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(customer), Encoding.UTF8,  "application/json")
            };

            var result = await _http.SendAsync(request);
```

which is not working either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After countless hours of searching I added

```
builder.AllowAnyHeader();
```

to my CORS settings in the startup.cs file.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                                  builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                                  builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                              });
        });
```

Now it's working :-).